# ZeroMQ data server topology

Tags: networking, zeromq

I want to use ZeroMQ for a very simple data server.

The server does no computation at all; it simply holds a chunk of data ( in the order of **a few `[GB]`** ) pulled from upstream. There are hundreds ( **up to `~1000 [1]`** ) **of clients** downloading the data frequently. Let's say 1024 clients.

To prevent overwhelming a single socket, I'll have multiple data servers keeping replicas of the data. Each server talks to an equal subset of the clients to reduce traffic ( e.g. 8 servers, each serve 128 clients ). I also want to enable automatic discovery, so that I can add or remove data servers without restarting the system.

The obvious pattern is **`ROUTER-DEALER`**, but it kind of defeats the purpose because the `DEALER` is still a single socket that will have to handle all traffic. `PUB-SUB` and `PUSH-PULL` are also not the right pattern because the server should only send data upon client's request.

I'd appreciate it if someone could come up with the right topology for the problem.

Comment: Given the posted scales of **`~ +1 [TB]`**, what is the ingress dataflow, coming from the cited ***"upstream"* in [GB/s]** that has to get delivered. Plus, does your definition seek a service, where a dataflow ought be served on demand, or providing any level of warranty of receiving all data as an uninterrupted sequence after a client next re-joins?

Comment: Let's say the ingress dataflow is a few Gb per second, updating the data held by the server. The clients only want the latest copy of data, and don't care about the older versions. Think about "parameter server" in machine learning, but without sharding.